# layout_weight on a ListView causes choiceMode to stop working

Tags: android, listview

This code is the minimal I could put together to demonstrate the problem (imports omitted for brevity). The problem is with the ListViews, if I set layout_weight on both ListViews to 1, then the page lays out correctly, but the choiceMode="singleChoice" does not display correctly (I.e. the selected item does not remain highlighted). If layout_weight is set to 0 or omitted, then the singleChoice highlighting works properly, but the screen elements jam together at the top.

I can't see a logical reason why these two should affect each other ... I tend toward calling it a bug, but more important to me is how to work around it.

Main layout XML:

```
<Button
    android:text="open new Activity"
    android:onClick="openNewActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test_list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#abcdef"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 </ListView>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/second_list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#abcdef"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>

<Button
    android:text="open new Activity"
    android:onClick="openNewActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyData data = new MyData(this);
    Cursor cursor = data.getCursor();

    String[] columns = new String[] {"name"};
    int[] fields = new int[] {R.id.item_text};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
      this,
      R.layout.item,
      cursor,
      columns,
      fields,
      0
    );

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.test_list);
    lv.clearChoices();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new MyListener(this));
  }

  public void openNewActivity(View v) {
    //
  }

}
```

The click listener:

```
public class MyListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

  MyActivity activity;

  public MyListener(MyActivity myActivity) {
    activity = myActivity;
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    ListView listView = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.second_list);
    MyData data = new MyData(activity);
    Cursor cursor = data.getCursor();

    String[] columns = new String[] {"name"};
    int[] fields = new int[] {R.id.item_text};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
      activity,
      R.layout.item,
      cursor,
      columns,
      fields,
      0
    );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listSelector is a static colour rather than a state list that supports selected and / or activated (depending which version you support)

Comment: The documentation states that one option for listSelector is `a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb"` : <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector>

I'm unsure what sort of `Drawable` object would be appropriate and am not finding any examples.